# "expected expression" error when initializing an empty array

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize an empty array that I initialized earlier in the program. However, whenever I compile my program I am given the error

> expected an expression (C/C++(29))

Here is what my code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 6;
    int array[MAX_SIZE] = {12,-3,24,65,92,11};
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    array[MAX_SIZE] = {};

    return 0;
}
```

The error is indicated right on the first curly brace of the empty array initialization. Also I am using Visual Studio Code on a Mac OS Big Sur.

Comment: You're not declaring an array, you're setting the element at MAZ_SIZE (which is bad).

Comment: *"I am trying to initialize an empty array that I initialized earlier"* -- The word "initialize" comes from the word "initial" meaning "first". Initializing a variable means giving that variable its **first** value. This is not something that can be done a second time. You might have meant "reset" or some variant on "assign".

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
array[MAX_SIZE] = {};
```

Attempts to assign a value at index 6 to something that isn't an array.  That's why it generates a compiler error.  (And if it didn't, it would be assigning something to an invalid index in an array!)

You might be temped to think this...

```
array = {};
```

...would work, since it's similar for resetting members of objects to a default initialized state.  But it doesn't work for arrays.

But this works:

```
std::fill(a, a+MAX_SIZE, 0);  // #include <algorithm> if needed
```

And will assign every element in `a` to `0`

Old school, "C" way for doing the same thing:

```
memset(a, '\0', MAX_SIZE*sizeof(int));  // #include <string.h> if needed
```

Or just manually

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble lies here:  `array[MAX_SIZE] = {};`

The initialization syntax *only* work when you are initializing an array.

Though it does actually compile for me with GCC, the resulting program then crashes.

If you want to fill the array with a value. Either zero or something else, you may want to use [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

Answer (score 0):

Plain C-style arrays are not assignable, the `type array[size] = {...};` syntax is only for declaration and initialisation.

You can use [`std::array<T,N>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, like this:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int MAX_SIZE = 6;
    std::array<int, MAX_SIZE> arr = {12,-3,24,65,92,11};

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    // reset all elements back to 0
    arr.fill(0);

    return 0;
}
```